# flutter: is it possible to send push notifications offline using FCM and cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, offline

i'm trying to build a dictionary app for both iOS and Android that sends 5-10 random words via notifications to the user on daily basis, and in this app im planning to send notifications using FCM and firebase cloud functions, and I was wondering if it was possible for the user to recieve the words(notifications) even if their device was offline and they didn't have access to Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 1):

Actually no.
But you can prepare these words in online mode and when push it with flutter local notifications package offline
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications